# Update data in access mdb database in c# form application " syntax error in update statement"

Tags: c#, database, winforms

I was working in C# form application with an MS-Access `mdb` database. I have a database in which I have a table `Customers` with two columns `CustomerId` And `Balance`. Both columns are of `integer` datatype.

Error I was getting is

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: **Syntax error in UPDATE statement.**
>
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
>   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>   at xml_and_db_test.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\my Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\xml_and_db_test\xml_and_db_test\Form1.cs:line 45

Codes I have tried till now are

```
try
{
   OleDbConnection con = new 
   OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\database_for_kissan_Pashu_AhaR_Bills.mdb");

   int balance = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
   int id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

   // int recordnumb = int.Parse(recordTextBox.Text);

   //  OleDbConnection oleDbConnection = new            OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Checkout-1\\Documents\\contact.accdb");    
   OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers  SET Balance = '" + balance + "',  WHERE id = " + id + " ", con);

   con.Open();
   update.ExecuteNonQuery();
   con.Close();

   // string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ?, where CustomerId = ?;";
   //string queryText = " 'UPDATE Customers SET Balance =' " + balance+ " ' WHERE CustomerId=  ' " +  id +  " ' " ;

   //OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryText, con);
   //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
   //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
   //cmd.Parameters.Add("Balance", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
   //cmd.Parameters.Add("CustomerId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);

   //con.Open(); // open the connection
   ////OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   //int yy = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   //con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string c = ex.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(c);
}

//try
//{
//    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\\my Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\xml_and_db_test\\xml_and_db_test\\bin\\Debug\\database_for_kissan_Pashu_AhaR_Bills.mdb");
//    string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ?, where CustomerId = ?;";

//    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryText, con);
//    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
//    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text));
//    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));

//    cmd.Parameters.Add("Balance", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

//    cmd.Parameters.Add("CustomerId", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
//    con.Open(); // open the connection
//    //OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//    int yy = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//    con.Close();

//}
//catch (Exception ex)
//{
//    string c = ex.ToString();
//    MessageBox.Show(c);

//}
//string connetionString = null;
//OleDbConnection connection;
//OleDbDataAdapter oledbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
//string sql = null;
//connetionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = G:\\my Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\xml_and_db_test\\xml_and_db_test\\bin\\Debug\\database_for_kissan_Pashu_AhaR_Bills.mdb;";
//connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
//sql = "update Customers set Balance = '1807' where CustomerId = '1'";
//try
//{
//    connection.Open();
//    oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
//    oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = sql;
//    oledbAdapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
//    MessageBox.Show("Row(s) Updated !! ");
//    connection.Close();
//}
//catch (Exception ex)
//{
//    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
//}
```

some codes are In comments and some are with every method i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Get rid of the comma after the set clause - you only have one variable being updated.  set xxx = xxx , where should be set xxx = xxx where.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As gzaxx said .. Try change this

```
string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ?, where CustomerId = ?;";
```

with

```
string queryText = "UPDATE Customers SET Balance = ? where CustomerId = ?;";
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a comma after balance in your query. Also you are casting your balance to `int32` yet you are inserting it as string because of single quote between it.

```
"UPDATE Customers  SET Balance = " + balance + "  WHERE id = " + id
```

this query should work.

Comment: OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers  SET Balance = " + balance + "  WHERE id = " + id, con);

Comment: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the comma after the set clause - you only have one variable being updated. set xxx = xxx , where should be set xxx = xxx where.

```
OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers  SET Balance = '" + balance + "'  WHERE id = " + id + " ", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

you just change it to

OleDbCommand update = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Customers  SET [Balance] = '" + balance + "',  WHERE [id] = " + id + " ", con);

and your code will work properly

Answer (score 1):

```
  OleDbCommand o_cmd = new OleDbCommand("Update tbl_SalesTax 
                       set tbl_SalesTax.SerialNumber='" + txtSerialNo.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.PartyCode='" + txtPartyCode.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.PartyName='" + txtPartyName.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.TinNumber='" + txtTinNo.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Gr='" + cmbgr.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Qty='" + txtQty.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Price='" + txtPrice.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Basic='" + txtBaisc.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Value='" + txtValue.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Total='" + txtTotal.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.Bags='" + txtBags.Text + "'
                      ,tbl_SalesTax.DumpCode='" + txtDumpCode.Text + "'
         where tbl_SalesTax.BookNumber='" + txtBookNo.Text + "'", my_con);
```